# Is there a linear-time algorithm for randomly sampling weighted combinations?

Tags: time-complexity, combinatorics, randomness

For concreteness, here's the specific problem description: suppose we have a set $S$ of $n$ items $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ with weights $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ respectively. The goal is to select a subset of size $k$ such that the probability of selecting the subset $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, \ldots, a_{i_k}$ is exactly $\dfrac{w_{i_1}\cdot w_{i_2}\cdots\cdot w_{i_k}}{\sum_{S_k\subseteq S, |S_k|=k}(\prod_{i\in S_k}w_i)}$. If $k=1$ then this is the usual selection from a weighted distribution and can easily be done in time $O(n)$ (or even $O(\log n)$ per sample with $O(n)$ preprocessing). If the $w_i$ are all equal then this is the usual uniform selection of a combination of $k$ things from a set of size $n$, and there are several well-established algorithms to do this in time $O(n)$. But I don't know of any algorithm for the generalized problem that runs faster than the naive version in $\Theta_n({n\choose k})=\Theta_n(n^k)$ time, and even a dip into TAOCP didn't turn up anything. Are there any known fast algorithms for this problem?

Comment: A strict subset, so sampling without replacement, right?

Comment: @orlp That's correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a very simple $O(n \log k)$ algorithm described in *Weighted random sampling with a reservoir* by Pavlos S. Efraimidis and Paul G. Spirakis, which can be summarized as:

> Associate value $r_i^{1/w_i}$ to $a_i$, where $r_i$ is an independent random uniform value on $[0, 1]$. Sort the elements by their associated values, the $k$ largest values indicate the desired subset.

With a priority queue of size $k$ you don't need to do a full sort and can get away with $O(n \log k)$.

---

To get some mathematical intuition of why this works, you can look at the $k = 2$ case. Let the cumulative density function $F_w(x) = \Pr[r^{1/w} \leq x] = \Pr[r \leq x^w] = x^w$, which gives the probability density function $f_w(x) = wx^{w-1}$. Then we have

$$\Pr[r_1^{1/w_1} \leq r_2^{1/w_2}] = \int_{0}^1 F_{w_1}(x)f_{w_2}(x)dx = \int_{0}^1w_2x^{w_1+w_2-1}dx = \frac{w_2}{w_1 + w_2}.$$

For the full method I recommend reading the paper.

Comment: Are you sure that's $r_i^{1/w_i}$ and not $r_i/w_i$? In the case of sampling a singleton from two things with weights $1$ and $100$ that would be comparing $R$ with $R^{1/100}$ and the latter is exponentially smaller than the former, but dividing out would seem to be correct there...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think you're confused about the effect of exponentiation here. Consider $R = 0.5$, then $R^{1/100}$ is not 'exponentially smaller' than $R$, in fact $R^{1/100} \approx 0.9931$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I expanded my answer a bit with the derivation of the probability for the 2-element case.

Comment: @orip you're right; I had mentally flipped things in my head, mea culpa!